# preg_replace() on encoded string in CI

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I have this encoded string

**hhNa0fUcOc3k0jUhPcRBJshpiXLpUSug+NhgPk89O7eSjerHk6go360U9rl8LazZo6DR6M1N4IqG0PYIwPyKhQ==**

and I used the `preg_replace()` to replace all the `+,/,= on` that string with `$`, but the result is just the same as above, the encoded string wasn't parsed well. Basically I wanted to just change all the `+=/` characters within that string for some security purposes. Here is what I did, following is my code snippet:

```
echo $code.'<br/>';
echo preg_replace('/\+\=\//', '$', $code);
```

where `$code` the one given earlier. I can't seem to find the problem why it doesn't replace the specified characters with the one i want.

Comment: For such a simple case you might as well use `str_replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the 3 characters in alternation (`|`) groups.

```
preg_replace('/\+|\=|\\//', '$', $code);
→ string(88) "hhNa0fUcOc3k0jUhPcRBJshpiXLpUSug$NhgPk89O7eSjerHk6go360U9rl8LazZo6DR6M1N4IqG0PYIwPyKhQ$$"
```

Your current code will match the sequence `+=/` instead of matching the characters individually.

Comment: ohh so that the reason, damn regex i really can't get that thing :D need to study more about that thing